# How to get pull request by id using JGit

Tags: jgit

I've started using JGit for achieving git api calls through java based jGit lib.
I'm looking to get stats around what has changed in pullRequest in files for that I'll need to get details of pullRequest.

I'm facing challenges in finding approach in getting pull request by ID using JGit.

There is no clear and concise documentation, the cook-book also don't cover this portion.

Answer (score 0):

PullRequests are not part of core Git, so JGit also does not have support.

So it depends on which Git server you are accessing, GitHub has support via special branches, e.g.

```
git fetch origin pull/ID/head:BRANCHNAME
```

e.g.

```
git fetch origin pull/223/head:local_test_branch
```

A similar fetch-command via JGit should work as well.

See https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/checking-out-pull-requests-locally for details

Comment: Thanks @centic for above explanation, i'm quite new to this devOps space and trying my hands with finding src and dst branches in PR raised on specific repositories. 
After visting above page I know there is git command which does this but how i'm able to achieve this using JGit is still a mystery for me. 
Even the CheckoutPullRequest impl class from cookbook doesn't tell me anything about PR.
Can you please redirect me to bit educative or clear example where I understand how this things wok with jGit.